# jsf-facelets forward bypass servlet filters

Tags: jsp, jsf, servlets, facelets, forward

For one week, i am playing with appfuse-jsf-basic but i noticed something. If i do not put  tag to my navigation rules, i can view a page that require ROLE_ADMIN with ROLE_USER rights. Then i understand something that facelets doesnt use "servlet.forward" methods for forwarding so filters does not catch facelets forwards in navigation rules. Is there any other way to use facelets with no-redirect  navigation rules and acegi(aka spring security).I searched all the forums but could not find a solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this library: http://dominikdorn.com/facelets/.